# Laravel validation if field one is filled field two should be empty

Tags: php, laravel, validation, validationrules

How can I validate if field end_date is filled, field start_time should be empty? something like: 'start_time'  => 'empty_with:end_date'

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'start_date'    => 'required',
        'end_date'      => 'nullable|after:start_date',
        'start_time'    => 'empty_with:end_date',
        'end_time'      => 'required_with:start_time',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `required_without`
 [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation) if you want the start_time to be required when end_date is empty

```
 'start_time'    => 'required_without:end_date',
```

> The field under validation must be present and not empty only when any of the other specified fields are not present.

Comment: Thanks madalinivascu but as I said above I need that the start_time is empty if the end_date has been filled.

Comment: you don't need validation for this, you can simply ignore the filed in the save function if the end_date is present, just toggle the start_date to disabled if the end_date is filled ,you don't need a extra validation, you will just confuse the user with a additional  validation